# Avoid repetitive xml code

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to achieve something similar to

[image]

I don't know how to create the green layout without creating 12 separate text views for the information below the horizontal line.

I do have an `activity_home.xml` file which contains

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/home_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="11dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:background="#118675"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_strength_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Strength score: "
                android:textColor="@color/main_text_green"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_strength_level"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/main_strength_number"
                android:text="Placeholder"
                android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_green" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/home_horizontal_line"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/main_strength_level"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@color/secondary_text_green" />


        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="11dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And looks like

[image]

Ignore button from the bottom right

I also have a `home_exercise.xml` which contains 3 textviews, for exercise name, strength level and strength number, for example in the first photo that could be "Squat" "intermediate" and "72.2"

Code looks as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/home_exercise_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="name placeholder"
        android:textColor="@color/main_text_green" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/home_exercise_level"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="72.2"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:textColor="@color/main_text_green"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/home_exercise_strength"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/home_exercise_name"
        android:text="Intermediate"
        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_green" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And looks like this

[image]

I'm unsure, however, how to combine those 2 files to achieve something similar to the app in the first picture or if it's even the right approach to begin with.

I'm also not sure, if I do merge 4 of `home_exercise.xml` layouts into `activity_home.xml`, how I will be able to differentiate all the TextViews from each others

Comment: use RecyclerView or ListView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number of rows is not constant, use a ListView or RecyclerView with a custom adapter.

If the number of rows is constant, you can use the `include` tag in your xml. The include tag allows you to specify ids.

XML Example:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/home_exercise_one"
    layout="@layout/home_exercise" />
```

Then it's a simple `findViewById(R.id.home_exercise_one)` call in your Java or Kotlin. To reference the children of the included xml, you will have to chain your findViewByIds like so: `findViewById(R.id.home_exercise_one).findViewById(R.id.home_exercise_name)`

Comment: I was also thinking about using a `RecyclerView` but I don't believe all the coding is worth it assuming it's only 4 rows (a constant number).

Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you :)